# how to change docker work_dir on CoreOS

Tags: linux, docker, coreos

I'm trying to change the default work_dir on CoreOS from /var/lib/docker to /mnt and not getting any luck yet. Tried placing "-g /mnt" in "systemd/system/docker.service.d/11-docker-namespaces.conf" (might not be the correct place to modify docker config?) however, not getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work another way, by creating symlink to the new location.

so it would be ln -s /mnt /var/lib/docker but the docker directory shouldn't be present already, if it does delete it first (of course take the backup first).